# Resolving dependencies with autofac (typeof vs generic)

Tags: c#, autofac

I was wondering if any of you are aware of the bellow lines of code producing different result:

This line resolves normally

```
var repo1 = ComponentContext.Resolve(typeof(IVersionedRepository<TR, T>));
```

while this one doesn't, it basically says the registration is not found. It must be something do to the way I registered the component and it' services, but my understanding was that the generic overload was just a shortcut to the non-generic.

```
var repo2 = ComponentContext.Resolve<IVersionedRepository<TR, T>>();
```

This forces me to then cast like the bellow which is not ideal, it works fine but it just makes the code less clean:

```
repository = ComponentContext.Resolve(typeof(IVersionedRepository<TR, T>)) as IVersionedRepository<TR, T>;
```

Maybe they execute in a different way, but my assumption was that the generic overload would also use typeof.

This is the registration I am using:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(VersionedRepository<,>))
    .As(typeof(IVersionedRepository<,>))
    .InstancePerDependency()
    .AsSelf()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Thanks

Comment: @KirkWoll comments like your come about because either you did not read the question properly or I am not explaining it in the right way, either way your comment does really apply. I will make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: I think you didn't explain it well enough (in my opinion), but your edit has clarified things. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll no my friend, the generic version works while the non-generic doesn't, sorry if it was not clear, I've updated it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `ComponentContext` exactly and where is it coming from? What _exactly_ is the exception, not "basically" but the actual message and possibly inner exception details?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue by resolving directly from container as well as from `IComponentContext` provided in call to `ContainerBuilder.Register`. I also tried different Autofac versions (4.*, 5.*, 6.*). Both ways worked as expected in every case.